# GCP Bigquery REGEX_REPLACE

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

The amount field in the ingested table is a string. Typical values will be like: £1,000.00

I would like to convert that into float. I'm using the following in the BigQuery:

```
SELECT SAFE_CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE('£1,000',r'(£)','') AS FLOAT64)
```

Then the output is: NULL

The reason for this is:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('£1,000',r'(£)','')
```

The output is: 1,000

Because of the comma (,) in the output, it is not able to convert the value into a Float in the SAFE_CAST.

How do I remove both '£' and ',' from the string '£1,000' using REGEXP_REPLACE?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SAFE_CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE('£1,000', r'[£,]', '') AS FLOAT64)
```

Comment: great! consider also voting up (if not yet) :o)